# Odd character in first column of datasource provided by CSV

Tags: c#, unit-testing, csv

I've got a CSV file that I added to a Visual Studio Unit Test project.  It has seven columns and looks like this:

```
assessmentitemid,reviewer1,reviewer2,reviewer3,reviewer4,reviewer5,reviewer6
```

My test method looks like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem("IntraclassCorrelationValues.csv")]
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\IntraclassCorrelationValues.csv", "IntraclassCorrelationValues#csv", Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    public void TestMethod1() {
        object val = TestContext.DataRow["assessmentitemid"];
    }
```

I get an error thrown when accessing the column assessmentitemid.  I checked the table and all the columns are mapped properly except for the assessmentitemid.  Its actual column name is this:

```
ï»¿assessmentitemid
```

Is there something else I have to do to the DataSource attribute in order for it to parse the CSV file correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the .csv file may have Unicode encoding.

Try opening it in Notepad and under 'Save As', select UTF-8, or ANSI instead.

Comment: You don't need to open in Notepad to save as ANSI, Just use Visual Studio's File -> Advanced Save Options. Change to Western European (Windows) Codepage 1252 and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a problem with the data file.

Change the character encoding on your source CSV file and re-save it, I think that'll fix the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a unicode byte order mark.